# Node registry error at the time of npm install

Tags: node.js, npm

I am getting registry error at the time of npm install.

[image]

```
npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! errno EPROTO
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/react failed, reason: write EPROTO 101057795:error:14077419:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert access denied:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:802:
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\badis\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-02-16T10_46_21_806Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the command prompt with admin privileges and follow the below steps:

1) Clear the `npm` cache using the following command:

`npm cache clean --force`

or

`npm cache verify`

2) Remove the `.npm` directory and the `node_modules` directory.

3) Also, Remove following:

- `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\` and
- `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache`

4) Set `npm` registry to the public repository using the following command:

`npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`.

5) Try running `curl https://registry.npmjs.org/package-name` from your terminal to make sure that network call is not blocking the package requests to `npm registry`.

If you are running behind a proxy, then you also have to configure `npm` to use it. You can set using:

- `npm config set proxy http://proxyhost:proxyport`
- `npm config set http-proxy http://proxyhost:proxyport`
- `npm config set https-proxy http://proxyhost:proxyport`

Comment: now i am getting bellow error `npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent request to http://registry.npmjs.org/express-generator failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOENT registry.npmjs.org:80
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent`

Answer (score 0):

Could be something wrong with your permission.

Check this: https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#permission-error

Answer (score -1):

Could be registry 404 issue
You could try to wait until it fixed on the registry side
[registry 404 screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yu534.png)

Comment: Please do not link to images of text, embed the text into the answer itself.

Comment: Unfortunately I need at least 10 reputation to post the image embedded :(